# Sum of all counts in a collections.Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

What is the best way of establishing the sum of all counts in a `collections.Counter` object?

I've tried:

`sum(Counter([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,6]))`

but this gives **21** instead of **9**?

Comment: It gives you the sum of the unique keys.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The code you have adds up the keys (i.e. the unique values in the list: `1+2+3+4+5+6=21`).

To add up the counts, use:

```
In [4]: sum(Counter([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,6]).values())
Out[4]: 9
```

This idiom is mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), under "Common patterns".

Comment: ...btw, this is always going to be equal to len([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,6]), so it use that method only when you just have the counter...

Answer (score 33):

Starting in `Python 3.10`, `Counter` is given a [`total()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter.total) function which provides the sum of the counts:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,6]).total()
# 9
```

Answer (score 28):

Sum the values:

```
sum(some_counter.values())
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,6])
>>> sum(c.values())
9
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(Counter([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,6]).values())
```