# Sum all values of a counter in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, counter

I have a counter from the `collections` module. What is the best way of summing all of the counts?

For example, I have:

```
 my_counter = Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
```

and would like to get the value `7` returned. As far as I can tell, the function `sum` is for adding multiple counters together.

Comment: if you had the source of the counter (e.g. `my_counter = Counter(source)`), you could just do `len(source)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your question is about Python 2.7, you should use something like this

```
sum(my_counter.itervalues())
```

which on Python 3.x is effectively equivalent to

```
sum(my_counter.values())
```

In both cases you evaluate the sum lazily and avoid expensive intermediate data structures. Beware of using the Python 3.x variant on Py 2.x, because in the latter case `my_counter.values()` calculates an entire list of counts and stores it in memory before calculating the sum.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sum(Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}).values())
7
```

> Common patterns for working with Counter objects: sum(c.values())
>   # total of all counts

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: Working correctly in Python 3.6.1!

Answer (score 0):

```
c = Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
len( list(c.elements()) )
```

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593519/sum-of-all-counts-in-a-collections-counter):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,6])
sum(c.values())
```