# Python collections.Counter: "AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'total'"

Tags: python, collections, counter, attributeerror

As the title says, I'm getting

```
>> Counter({'red': 2, 'blue': 1}).total()
AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'total'
```

even though [it definitely does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.total)? Really at a loss here, thanks in advance!

I tried running it in another compiler, and that worked.

Comment: `New in version 3.10.`

Comment: Okay wow, oversaw that one, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Terry Spotts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13629751/terry-spotts) pointed out, this method is only available in Python version >=3.10.

Easy workaround:

`sum(Counter_object.values())`

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593563/8739121).